# Mysql Between query in elasticsearch

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

Currently I am Working on Elastic Search For My Current Project. I need MySql BETWEEN in my elastic. I searched So Many Examples But Not Get Any Solution I need to sort using no. of employees by Company. I already Wrote Some Filters Its Working Fine. But I Need Range Filter. and my code as follows

```
$query = array("from" => $start,
                "size" => $recordslimit,
                "sort" => array(array('id' => 'desc')),
              "query" => array(
                    "filtered" => array(
                        "query" => array("match_all" => array()),
                        "query" => (!empty($keyword)) ? array("match" => array('_all' => $keyword)) : null,
                        "filter" => array(
                            "bool" => array(
                                'should' => array(
                                    array("match" => array('location' => $headerLocation))
                                ),
                                'must' => array(
                                    ($type == '1') ? array('term' => array('user_sub_type' => '1')) : null,
                                    array('term' => array('user_type' => 'v')),
                                    array('term' => array('status' => 'a'))

                                ),
                                'must_not' => array(
                                    array('term' => array('subscription_type' => 'n'))
                                ))
                            )
            ))


            );
        }
    }

    $data = $this->elasticsearch->advancedquery("users",json_encode($query));
```

this is current query.. and also i add in filter

```
                            "range" => array(
                                'num_of_employees' => array(
                                    'gt' => 100,
                                    'lte' => 1000
                                )
                            )
```

please helpout with this situation. Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: The `range` query/filter is the correct choice. Can you describe what doesn't work then?

Comment: I am geting result but Wrong result... i.e i got companies having above 1000 (employees) also. and less than 10 also

Comment: Have you added it to `must` or `should`? Also can you share the mapping of `num_of_employees`?

Comment: But i need companies have greaterthan 100 and lessthan or equal to 1000 (employees) in between only

Comment: No.. i use range in filter only

Comment: yes, but which one? `bool/must` or `bool/should`? Please show your entire query, otherwise it's guesswork.

Comment: this is query  i used...  $query = array("from" => $start,
                    "size" => $recordslimit,
                    "sort" => array(array('id' => 'desc')),
                    'query' => array(
                        "filtered" => array(
                            "filter" => array(
                                "range" => array(
                                    'num_of_employees' => array(
                                        'gt' => 100,
                                        'lte' => 1000))))));

Comment: in this above query i need only filter for no.of employees.. this time i got wrong result.

Comment: Also can you share the mapping of `num_of_employees`?

Comment: sorry for saying.. actually i dont know any idea about mapping. can you please tell me what is mapping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100474/discussion-between-kishan-kurivella-and-val).